# Node.js reloading module bug

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, long-running-processes

I'm reloading a module this way:

```
require('./module.js');             // require the module
delete require.cache('/module.js'); // delete module from cache
require('/module.js');              // re-require the module
```

But there is a problem if the module contains something like this:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    console.log('hello!'); 
}, 1000);
```

Every time I reload the module  a new `setInterval` is called, but the last one is NOT closed.

Is there any way to know about each module's (long) running functions so I can stop them before I require it again? Or any suggestions how can I make this work?

*I'm open to any crazy ideas.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a wild guess but you may be able to load the module within a [domain](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html).

When you are done use domain.dispose() to clear the timers:

> The dispose method destroys a domain, and makes a best effort attempt
>   to clean up any and all IO that is associated with the domain. Streams
>   are aborted, ended, closed, and/or destroyed. **Timers are cleared.**
>   Explicitly bound callbacks are no longer called. Any error events that
>   are raised as a result of this are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply set a reference to the interval and expose a method in order to stop it like:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    console.log('hello');
}, 1000);

var clearInt = clearInterval(interval);
```

I dont think you can hook into any events as you are simply deleting a reference. If it doesnt exist anymore it reloads. Before you do this call the clearInt function.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `IntervalRegistry` in your main application:

```
global.IntervalRegistry = {
    intervals : {},
    register  : function(module, id) {
      if (! this.intervals[module])
      {
        this.intervals[module] = [];
      }
      this.intervals[module].push(id);
    },
    clean     : function(module) {
      for (var i in this.intervals[module])
      {
        var id = this.intervals[module][i];
        clearInterval(id);
      }
      delete this.intervals[module];
    }
  };
```

In your module, you would register the interval created there:

```
// module.js
IntervalRegistry.register(__filename, setInterval(function() {
  console.log('hello!');
}, 1000));
```

When it's time to clean up, call this:

```
var modulename = '/full/path/to/module.js'; // !!! see below
IntervalRegistry.clean(modulename);
delete require.cache[modulename];
```

Remember that modules are stored with their full filename in `require.cache`.